# How to remove "Connection refused" lines from ">/dev/tcp/ip/port"

Tags: io-redirection

Open port

```
user@linux:~$ >/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/8080 && echo open || echo closed
open
user@linux:~$
```

Closed port

```
user@linux:~$ >/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/8088 && echo open || echo closed
bash: connect: Connection refused
bash: /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/8088: Connection refused
closed
user@linux:~$
```

Redirection stderr to /dev/null didn't work

```
user@linux:~$ >/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/8088 2>/dev/nul
bash: connect: Connection refused
bash: /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/8088: Connection refused
user@linux:~$
```

Desired Output

```
user@linux:~$ >/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/8088 && echo open || echo closed
closed
user@linux:~$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverse the order of redirections and let `bash` know what stderr should be before stdin

```
$ >/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/8088 2>/dev/nul
bash: connect: Connection refused
bash: /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/8088: Connection refused
$ 2>/dev/null >/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/8088 && echo open || echo closed
closed
$
```

---

The reason why the first version fails is that redirections are processed in the order of their appearance, so in `>/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/8088 2>/dev/null` when redirection to the port happens , the stderr stream has NOT been redirected just yet. You can clearly see the corresponding syscall `dup2()` to redirect stderr ( or lack thereof in the case of command that fails) in the diagnostic output with `strace` utility

```
$ strace -e dup2,connect  -f bash -c '>/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/8088 2>/dev/null'
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(8088), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16) = -1 ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
bash: connect: Connection refused
bash: /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/8088: Connection refused
+++ exited with 1 +++
$ strace -e dup2,connect  -f bash -c '2>/dev/null >/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/8088 '
dup2(3, 2)                              = 2
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(8088), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16) = -1 ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
dup2(10, 2)                             = 2
+++ exited with 1 +++
$
```

Comment: Thanks!!! I really appreciate the detailed answer especially on `strace` part.